# Terraform Ansible job marked as failed, although it deployed correctly scp stderr: "Sink: C0644 0 terraform.sh" Error while provisioning null_resource

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, sink

**My terraform is spinning up two instances, and deploying the same two ansible playbooks on both:**

```
resource "aws_instance" "X360Instance" {
  count                       = var.MultiNode ? 2 : 1
  ami                         = var.AMIID
  instance_type               = var.InstanceType
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.MasterKey.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.X360SG.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.Public.id
  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 100
  }

###Assign a Name tag to the target machine instance. This tag is referenced by passed_in_hosts.

  tags = {
    Name = "X360tf"
    App = "Node${count.index}"
  }

###Wait for the route table to be available

  depends_on = [aws_route_table_association.PublicRTA]

###Connect to the target machine using the keys in the local .ssh directory

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = var.Secrets ? "${local.secrets.TargetUser}" : var.TargetUser
    private_key = file(pathexpand("~/.ssh/id_rsa"))
    host        = coalesce(self.public_ip, self.private_ip)
  }
}
 
resource "null_resource" "ExecuteAnsible" {
  count         = var.MultiNode ? 2 : 1
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host      = "${element(aws_instance.X360Instance.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
      #host     = coalesce(aws_instance.X360Instance[count.index].public_ip, aws_instance.X360Instance[count.index].private_ip)
      user      = var.Secrets ? "${local.secrets.TargetUser}" : var.TargetUser
      private_key       = file(pathexpand("~/.ssh/id_rsa"))
    }
    inline = ["echo 'connected!'"]
  }

###Execute the PostgresInstaller ansible playbook on the target machine
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
  ansible-playbook --extra-vars "@AnsiblePlaybooks/Variables.json" AnsiblePlaybooks/PostgresInstaller.yml
  EOF
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
  ansible-playbook --extra-vars "@AnsiblePlaybooks/Variables.json" AnsiblePlaybooks/X360Installer.yml
  EOF
  }
}
```

**The two instances are deployed and both playbooks are executed on both. I can reach the application that was deployed by the ansible playbooks on both ec2 instances, so I know the playbooks executed correctly. However, at the end, I get the message saying 0 failures, but instead of showing the outputs, it fails to this error:**

```
null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[1] (local-exec): PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[1] (local-exec): 3.83.34.169                : ok=51   changed=34   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=5    rescued=0    ignored=5
null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[1] (local-exec): 3.83.94.204                : ok=51   changed=34   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=5    rescued=0    ignored=5

null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[1]: Creation complete after 7m57s [id=7711336021038131401]
╷
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[0],
│   on instances.tf line 226, in resource "null_resource" "ExecuteAnsible":
    │  226:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│ Error running command '  ansible-playbook --extra-vars "@AnsiblePlaybooks/Variables.json" AnsiblePlaybooks/PostgresInstaller.yml
│ ': exit status 2. Output: ies.", "Unable to read consumer identity", "", "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use
│ subscription-manager to register.", "", "Waiting for process with pid 5991 to finish.", "Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:21 ago on Tue 31 May 2022 10:02:50 PM
│ UTC.", "Dependencies resolved.", "================================================================================", " Package            Architecture Version
│ Repository          Size", "================================================================================", "Installing:", " createrepo_c       x86_64
│ 0.17.7-3.el8          @commandline        89 k", "", "Transaction Summary", "================================================================================",
│ "Install  1 Package", "", "Total size: 89 k", "Installed size: 189 k", "Downloading Packages:", "Running transaction check", "Transaction check succeeded.", "Running
│ transaction test"]}
│ fatal: [3.83.34.169]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo yum localinstall Postgres12/RHEL8/drpm-* -y --nogpgcheck \nsudo yum localinstall
│ Postgres12/RHEL8/createrepo_c-libs* -y --nogpgcheck\nsudo yum localinstall Postgres12/RHEL8/createrepo_c-0* -y --nogpgcheck\n", "delta": "0:00:38.637174", "end":
│ "2022-05-31 22:03:15.089383", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-05-31 22:02:36.452209", "stderr": "Error: Transaction test error:\n  package
│ drpm-0.4.1-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed\n\nError: Transaction test error:\n  package createrepo_c-libs-0.17.7-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed\n\nError:
│ Transaction test error:\n  package createrepo_c-0.17.7-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed", "stderr_lines": ["Error: Transaction test error:", "  package
│ drpm-0.4.1-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed", "", "Error: Transaction test error:", "  package createrepo_c-libs-0.17.7-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed", "",
│ "Error: Transaction test error:", "  package createrepo_c-0.17.7-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed"], "stdout": "Updating Subscription Management
│ repositories.\nUnable to read consumer identity\n\nThis system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to
│ register.\n\nWaiting for process with pid 5943 to finish.\nLast metadata expiration check: 0:00:10 ago on Tue 31 May 2022 10:02:51 PM UTC.\nDependencies
│ resolved.\n================================================================================\n Package       Architecture    Version              Repository
│ Size\n================================================================================\nInstalling:\n drpm          x86_64          0.4.1-3.el8          @commandline
│ 68 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nInstall  1 Package\n\nTotal size: 68 k\nInstalled
│ size: 136 k\nDownloading Packages:\nRunning transaction check\nTransaction check succeeded.\nRunning transaction test\nUpdating Subscription Management
│ repositories.\nUnable to read consumer identity\n\nThis system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to
│ register.\n\nWaiting for process with pid 5965 to finish.\nLast metadata expiration check: 0:00:16 ago on Tue 31 May 2022 10:02:51 PM UTC.\nDependencies
│ resolved.\n================================================================================\n Package                Arch        Version             Repository
│ Size\n================================================================================\nInstalling:\n createrepo_c-libs      x86_64      0.17.7-3.el8
│ @commandline      118 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nInstall  1 Package\n\nTotal size:
│ 118 k\nInstalled size: 258 k\nDownloading Packages:\nRunning transaction check\nTransaction check succeeded.\nRunning transaction test\nUpdating Subscription
│ Management repositories.\nUnable to read consumer identity\n\nThis system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to
│ register.\n\nLast metadata expiration check: 0:00:20 ago on Tue 31 May 2022 10:02:51 PM UTC.\nDependencies
│ resolved.\n================================================================================\n Package            Architecture Version               Repository
│ Size\n================================================================================\nInstalling:\n createrepo_c       x86_64       0.17.7-3.el8
│ @commandline        89 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nInstall  1 Package\n\nTotal size:
│ 89 k\nInstalled size: 189 k\nDownloading Packages:\nRunning transaction check\nTransaction check succeeded.\nRunning transaction test", "stdout_lines": ["Updating
│ Subscription Management repositories.", "Unable to read consumer identity", "", "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use
│ subscription-manager to register.", "", "Waiting for process with pid 5943 to finish.", "Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:10 ago on Tue 31 May 2022 10:02:51 PM
│ UTC.", "Dependencies resolved.", "================================================================================", " Package       Architecture    Version
│ Repository             Size", "================================================================================", "Installing:", " drpm          x86_64
│ 0.4.1-3.el8          @commandline           68 k", "", "Transaction Summary", "================================================================================",
│ "Install  1 Package", "", "Total size: 68 k", "Installed size: 136 k", "Downloading Packages:", "Running transaction check", "Transaction check succeeded.", "Running
│ transaction test", "Updating Subscription Management repositories.", "Unable to read consumer identity", "", "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription
│ Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.", "", "Waiting for process with pid 5965 to finish.", "Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:16 ago on Tue
│ 31 May 2022 10:02:51 PM UTC.", "Dependencies resolved.", "================================================================================", " Package
│ Arch        Version             Repository         Size", "================================================================================", "Installing:", "
│ createrepo_c-libs      x86_64      0.17.7-3.el8        @commandline      118 k", "", "Transaction Summary",
│ "================================================================================", "Install  1 Package", "", "Total size: 118 k", "Installed size: 258 k",
│ "Downloading Packages:", "Running transaction check", "Transaction check succeeded.", "Running transaction test", "Updating Subscription Management repositories.",
│ "Unable to read consumer identity", "", "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.", "", "Last
│ metadata expiration check: 0:00:20 ago on Tue 31 May 2022 10:02:51 PM UTC.", "Dependencies resolved.",
│ "================================================================================", " Package            Architecture Version               Repository
│ Size", "================================================================================", "Installing:", " createrepo_c       x86_64       0.17.7-3.el8
│ @commandline        89 k", "", "Transaction Summary", "================================================================================", "Install  1 Package", "",
│ "Total size: 89 k", "Installed size: 189 k", "Downloading Packages:", "Running transaction check", "Transaction check succeeded.", "Running transaction test"]}
│
│ PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
│ 3.83.34.169                : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=6    rescued=0    ignored=0
│ 3.83.94.204                : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=6    rescued=0    ignored=0
│
│
```

╵

**I set the logging to terraform.log and ran the apply with  *TF_LOG=DEBUG OS_DEBUG=true terraform apply*  But, you can see that when I tail the log, it cuts out at a sink error, and then doesn't record anything for about 10 minutes while the deployment runs, then picks back up with a few errors at the end:**

```
2022-05-31T22:02:03.798Z [DEBUG] opening new ssh session
2022-05-31T22:02:03.819Z [DEBUG] starting remote command: /tmp/terraform_882212444.sh
2022-05-31T22:02:04.346Z [DEBUG] remote command exited with '0': /tmp/terraform_882212444.sh
2022-05-31T22:02:04.346Z [DEBUG] opening new ssh session
2022-05-31T22:02:04.355Z [DEBUG] Starting remote scp process:  'scp' -vt /tmp
2022-05-31T22:02:04.399Z [DEBUG] Started SCP session, beginning transfers...
2022-05-31T22:02:04.399Z [DEBUG] Copying input data into temporary file so we can read the length
2022-05-31T22:02:04.400Z [DEBUG] Beginning file upload...
2022-05-31T22:02:04.653Z [DEBUG] SCP session complete, closing stdin pipe.
2022-05-31T22:02:04.653Z [DEBUG] Waiting for SSH session to complete.
2022-05-31T22:02:04.665Z [ERROR] scp stderr: "Sink: C0644 0 terraform_882212444.sh\n"
2022-05-31T22:03:15.271Z [WARN]  Errors while provisioning null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[0] with "l        ocal-exec", so aborting
2022-05-31T22:03:15.275Z [ERROR] vertex "null_resource.ExecuteAnsible[0]" error: local-exec provis        ioner error
2022-05-31T22:09:59.841Z [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error         : code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2022-05-31T22:09:59.842Z [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/regis         try.terraform.io/hashicorp/null/3.1.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-null_v3.1.1_x5 pid=8933
2022-05-31T22:09:59.842Z [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
```

**I don't know how to resolve this sink error, I don't know why my logging is cutting out for 10 minutes. I also can't figure out why the job is marked as failed even though I see 0 failures in the summary, and the app has been deployed. Any help would be so much appreciated. been banging my head against the wall for a week on this.**

Comment: While off-topic for a programming stack exchange, how much more explicit of an error are you expecting to receive than `Unable to read consumer identity\nThis system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.`?

Answer (score 0):

The "Sink: C0644" errors and the "provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop" errors were just red herrings. The actual problem was that the way I had my null_resource set, it was trying to execute each playbook on each node twice. Here's the corrected:

```
resource "null_resource" "ExecuteAnsible" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host      = "${aws_instance.X360Instance[0].public_ip}"
      user      = var.Secrets ? "${local.secrets.TargetUser}" : var.TargetUser
      private_key       = file(pathexpand("~/.ssh/id_rsa"))
    }
    inline = ["echo 'connected!'"]
  }

###Execute the PostgresInstaller ansible playbook on the target machine

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
  ansible-playbook --extra-vars "@AnsiblePlaybooks/Variables.json" AnsiblePlaybooks/PostgresInstaller.yml
  EOF
  }

###Execute the X360Installer ansible playbook on the target machine

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
  ansible-playbook --extra-vars "@AnsiblePlaybooks/Variables.json" AnsiblePlaybooks/X360Installer.yml
  EOF
  }
}
```